# Compiling source code package for Android

Tags: android, bash, compilation, android-ndk

I'm new to android and have been trying to compile the SoundTouch source code package for android using the provided steps: http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/README-SoundTouch-Android.html

I'm having trouble defining the location of the NDK installation ("NDK").
Here's how the instructions say how to do it:

"Notice that to allow Cygwin/bash to locate the NDK compile scripts, you need to define the location of the NDK installation defined in environment variable "NDK". That's easiest done by adding the NDK path definition at end of your ~/.bash_profile file, for instance as follows:

```
NDK=/cygdrive/d/Android/android-ndk-r6
```

"

I'm unsure of where to set the path of NDK. I've tried defining in it the Cygdrive terminal but that hasn't worked. I have the Android NDK, SDK and CygDrive installed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI3u6.png << Image as I'm lacking the rep required to include one in the post.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Where have you installed the NDK? Also, there's no need to post console output as an image. You can just post the text instead.

Comment: Hi @Michael, I've actually managed to solve my problem (and manage to compile for android) since posting this question. I'm now trying to figure out what to do with these new .so files and such. I'll post up my solution later on. From my googling it seems a lot of people have trouble with the SoundTouch package. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed $ before NDK.

Write it as:

```
$NDK/ndk-build
```